# Constant minimization of a slowly time varying function

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, minimization

Is there an algorithm to constantly minimize a function that maintains its rough shape over time but may drift (slowly) in its absolute position?

I have a feedback loop in some hardware where I want to keep parameter X to a minimum. Parameter X can be minimized by adjusting parameter Y, but the exact value of Y that minimizes X drifts over time. In this case the parameter X/Y relationship is roughly quadratic.

My naive solution so far just repeatedly minimizes X using e.g. hill climbing, and with the initial guess being the result of the previous minimization. Is there a better solution?

Comment: IMHO how to efficiently minimize X = f(Y) first of all depends on f. If f is just a quadratic function then you can calculate the minimum analytically pretty quickly at each time step. If f is more complicated but differentiable then gradient descent should work to find a local minimum even if the function f is changing slowly over time.

Comment: You should describe the model in more details. As of now, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Your second paragraph is confusing. The second sentence starts, *Parameter X can be minimized by adjusting parameter Y,* but then it goes on to talk about using X to minimize Y. Can you re-read that sentence and make sure you have your X and Y references right?

Comment: @JimMischel Apologies I have now edited for clarity

Comment: @user58697 Which aspect of the model needs more detail?